# How to apply Unique key constraint on 2 columns in the table when the values in the table are showing error

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found 
for the object name 'dbo.tblhm' and the index name 'New_id1'. The duplicate 
key value is (45560, 44200).
```

i want to know how to work on unique key constraint taking 2 columns together.Such that the values previously stored in the database are not in that format.Such it is showing me the above error ,So how to overcome that so that all the work can be done and no column value in the database gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you have a duplicate key which you want to ignore but still want to apply a unique constraint going forward? I don't think this is possible. Either you need to remove the duplicate row (or update it such that it is not a duplicate), move the duplicated data into an archive table without a unique index or add the index to the existing table without a unique constraint.

I stand to be corrected, but I don't think there is any other way round this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ,actually i m thinking the same Rohland

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you are creating a Unique Index on columns : `column1` and `column2` in your table `dbo.tblhm`

This would assume that there is no repitition of any combination of `column1, column2` values in any rows in table `dbo.tblhm`

As per your error, the following combination `(45560, 44200)` of values for `column1, column2` is present in more than 1 row and hence the constraint fails.

What you need to do is to clean up your data first using an UPDATE statement to change the `column1 or column2` values in the rows that are duplicates BEFORE you try to create the constraint.

AFAIK, in Oracle you have the " `novalidate`" keyword which can be used to achieve what you want to do without cleaning up the existing data. But atleast I am not aware of any way to achieve that in SQL Server without first cleaning up the data

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it says - there is more than one row with the same key.

i.e. for

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX New_id1 on dbo.tblhm(Column1, Column2)
```

there is more than one row with the same values for Column1 and Column2

So either

- Your data is corrupt (e.g. inserting without checking for duplicates) - you will need to find and merge / delete duplicate keys before recreating the index
- Or your Index can't be unique (e.g. there is a valid reason why there can be more than one row with this key, e.g. at a business level).